# How to display 40+ buttons programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, pos

I'm building a small Point Of Sale app for a friend. She needs an app on a tablet that has 40 add button (and 40 remove buttons). Each button represents a Product and has a different label.
The left side of the screen should have 20 stacked vertical buttons, and the right side should also have 20 stacked vertical buttons. All buttons should fit on one screen.

I have tried to use two recyclerviews next to each other - fixed to screen size - with the same adapter and custom views inside each recyclerview but this caused a lot of lag and I got warnings in my emulator that frames were skipped. I think this is because the large amount of views inside the recyclerview (80+ buttons).

I then tried 1 recyclerview with two products on 1 horizontal line,  but this didn't seem to improve performance and complicates my app (because I need to set two products per line).
I've also tried using ListView because I thought it had less overhead, but kept getting lag and  "I/Choreographer: Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."

The only way that no frames seem to be skipped is when I hardcode the 80 buttons, but this is not an optimal solution because the amount of products will change over time. When the products change (saved in a csv) the amount of buttons should also update without having to change code.

Is there a way I can create a View with the 80 buttons that is less demanding on the system? Ideally I would input 1 list of Product in 1 View.

Example of 1 Product:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingHorizontal="10dip"
    android:paddingTop="1dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_button"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:minHeight="1dip"
        android:text="BUT L"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:paddingHorizontal="20dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete_button"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:minWidth="1dip"
        android:minHeight="1dip"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried clickable labels perhaps instead of buttons? Perhaps thats less intensive to draw then buttons. It would also help to post a short piece of code that reproduces the issue as this will make it easier to reproduce and you are more likely to get an answer quicker

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about skipped frames messages in the log personally - that's more to do with how your emulator is running on your machine, if there's a Garbage Collection happening, what else is going on with the system and other apps...

`RecyclerView`s are the correct way to do this - they're designed to be efficient! The old `ListView` approach would create your 40 entries with their own `Button` views - `RecyclerViews` only create a few (enough to fill the screen and a couple either side so they can peek in when you scroll).

Then they *recycle* them by taking a `ViewHolder` that's scrolled off the screen, and filling it with the data for an item that's about to scroll into view (this is what the `onBindViewHolder` method is about, filling in that data). So you only have a handful of `ViewHolders` with their view layouts, and it doesn't matter if your list represents 40 items or 40,000!

---

Really you should profile the performance on a real device, but you shouldn't be having any problems with a basic `RecyclerView` layout, that's hardly anything in UI terms. If you like you could post your `Adapter` and `ViewHolder` code and people can tell you if you're doing anything super slow or memory-intensive in the actual handling logic.

Also make sure you're looking up the UI elements *once* for each `ViewHolder` you create, and store them as properties you can set in `onBindViewHolder`. If you're running `findViewById` in `onBindViewHolder` (which remember, runs every time an item is getting ready to be scrolled into view) that's a lot of duplicated work. Probably won't be glitchy in this case, but still best to avoid it if you can!